# How to create a function that adds or calls an other function after an already called function. PHP

Tags: php, function

Im not sure about the name of this...I'd want to make something like WordPress has. The `add_action` function that calls a function after a function.

Something like this:

```
add_action('the_function()','the_function_to_add()');
```

Alright, I figured out how to add a function before one. But is it possible to add after one?

To add before : `call_user_func('barber', func(), func2() );` adds the func() and func2() before the berber() function.

Comment: Are you basically wanting to call an arbitrary function name?

Comment: Your call_user_func is effectively calling barber(func(), func2()). As Wesley stated, you may not need this. If you can expand on exactly what you're trying to accomplish, you'll get better answers.

Comment: What I want to is be able to call function before and after a specific function, while adding the code to a different function

Comment: whats the problem with adding the function calls explicitly?

Comment: There's no problem with it. I'm working on a CMS, and I want to give theme and plugin creators more freedom. It's just a project I'm learning on but still.

Comment: added some sample code below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Wordpress [add_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) creates a hook to a specific Wordpress action. The function is then called at some point where the action triggers itself.

This is similar to an event dispatcher, where `add_action` acts as a dispatcher which decouples the code calling your given function from the function itself. When an event (the action) is triggered, the dispatcher can call all the registered functions.

As to the implementation, it's not found in PHP natively as a set of functions, but it could be created reasonably easily.

**EDIT**

Here's one such implementation:

```
<?php 

class Dispatcher {

    // Event ID to callback functions array
    private $callbacks = array();

    function subscribe($event_id, $callback) {
        if (!isset($this->callbacks[$event_id])) {
            $this->callbacks[$event_id] = array();
        }
        $this->callbacks[$event_id][] = $callback;
        var_dump($this->callbacks);
    }

    function publish($event_id, $obj = NULL) {
        $callbacks = $this->callbacks[$event_id];
        if ($callbacks) {
            foreach ($callbacks as $callback) {
                call_user_func($callback, $obj);
            }
        }
    }

}

// This object would be shared where appropriate (hopefully you can avoid a global object!)
$dispatcher = new Dispatcher();

// Your code
function receiver($obj) {
    echo "Receiver got " . $obj;
}
$dispatcher->subscribe('test-event', 'receiver');

// Somewhere else, possibly in someone else's code in a different class
$dispatcher->publish('test-event', 123);

?>
```

The output:

```
array(1) {
  ["test-event"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "receiver"
  }
}
Receiver got 123
```

The first array is just for understanding what the `$callbacks` stores. Whenever the "test-event" event is published, all the registered callback functions will be executed.

If this were Wordpress, `add_action` would be the `subscribe` in your own code, and `publish` would be `do_action` which is called in Wordpress' own code.

For this simple example I've allowed an arbitrary object to be passed during the `publish`.

Finally, if you're working with a decent framework this is surely implemented somewhere in it already, but hopefully this example shows how easy and useful it can be.

Comment: Oh I see. And how can it be created? Can you help me with it?

Comment: Thanks. And I'm not using a FrameWork yet. Building my own :) Thanks again

Comment: Is there a way to also determinate if I want it before or after the already existing function?

Comment: @And0r1995 not sure what you mean. Do you mean what happens if you publish before subscribing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`override_function()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) or [`runkit_function_redefine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php) to replace the function with your own implementation. That implementation could call the original implementation and then call whatever was added using `add_action`. Both functions are only available as PECL extensions.

This is also not the way that WordPress does it. The function, that you extend using [`add_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) is from the beginning implemented in a way that is meant to be extendible using [`add_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action). Functions that can be extended using [`add_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) call [`do_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) at some point during their execution. This is simply the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Comment: Do I need to create the override_function or the runkit_function_redefine() function? Since it returns undefined function.

Comment: You have to install the PECL extension that provides the function.